# FT not working propertly with Google Apps Script

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I create a library with functions to insert data into a Fusion Table.This functions work fine.

Then, I create a new GAS proyect including this library. When I try to invoke the library function to insert data in FT, I always obtain "Authorizacion Requires". I grant the authorization all the times but it doesn't work (I'm the owner of all the GAS proyects and FT).

This is the url I see in Logs. The oAuth parameters are correct: UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query, {oAuthServiceName=fusiontables, payload=sql=INSERT INTO 1MzzGAWuSZv_A1ETirCEHE8xWM5uBu7f3bJ0VPSc ('idProyecto','tipoNotificacion','idDocumento','fechaSolicitud','estado') values('dcccc','Eliminación IC','','Thu Aug 16 2012 13:36:41 GMT+0200 (CEST)','0'), oAuthUseToken=always, method=post}])

regards

Comment: If you can isolate the problem down to a smaller sample script you'd be more likely to get some replies.

Comment: I did Eric. I hope with this new descripcion of the problem maybe someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Did you get any furhter with this @user1587167?